# SlidingMenu showSecondaryMenu does not work correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I'm using SlidingMenu library (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) for Android.

I have a left and right menu, left works fine when opened with swipe gesture or toggle() method. The problem is with right menu, it works fine when opened with swipe but when calling showSecondaryMenu() it just inflates the layout for the menu but does not let me click any component.

This is the layout for the secondary menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/search_sliding_menu_layout" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_sliding_menu_edittext_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search_sliding_menu_textview_filter_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/search_sliding_layout_subtitle" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/search_sliding_menu_expandablelistview_filters"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >
</ExpandableListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/search_sliding_layout_btn_filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/search_sliding_layout_btn_filter" 
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the onCreateView for the fragment:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle         savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_sliding_menu_layout, null);
    filters = (ExpandableListView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_sliding_menu_expandablelistview_filters);
    filter_btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_sliding_layout_btn_filter);
    claimSearch = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_sliding_menu_edittext_search);
    return convertView;
}
```

And this is how I call I start the rigth menu from the activity:

```
getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two,  new MyFragment())
    .commit();
getSlidingMenu().showSecondaryMenu();
```